# fopen doesn´t work with something different than r php

Tags: php, fopen

I have a problem with the fopen function and the opening mode argument.

## Code

```
function writeOnFile($url, $text)
{
    $fp = fopen($url, "r");
    echo "<br>read: ".fgets($fp);
    //fwrite($fp, $text);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If I use "r" as the opening mode the echo line works... but if I change this argument for any other (using the same url file) it stops working and only see "read:" and nothing else.
I tried with "w+" "r+" "a+"... but no one works.
What I am trying to read is a txt file and I changed the permissions of the file and now are 777...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you grant execution permissions if you only want to read/write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your variable naming, `$url` suggests you're trying to write to a `http://example.com/...`. This is not possible. You cannot "write" to a url, because PHP has absolutely **NO** idea what protocol the remote server is expecting. E.g. PHP by some miracle decides to let this URL through, and uses http `POST`... but the server is expecting an http `PUT`. Ooops, that won't work.

As well, never EVER assume an operation on an external resource succeeded. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise:

```
function writeOnFile($url, $text)
   if (!is_writeable($url)) {
      die("$url is not writeable");
   }
   $fp = fopen($url, "w");
   if (!$fp) {
      die("Unable to open $url for writing");
   }
   etc...
}
```

Comment: Forgive the delay... uuppps!! I was using a absolute url, I didn´t know that I doesn´t work (but that makes sense, but someone could modify files from other server, or something similar).
Thank you very much.