# php code to Save pdf file which was generated by php code

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, createfile

I have created PDF using php code following these tutorials 
https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_generate_pdf_files_with_php/

The .pdf displays correctly on web browser. 
I need to save this .pdf file on the specific folder on my local machine. 
Please help me to do so. 
I tried

```
file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent);
```

but it is always returning false.

Comment: 1. Make sure the path exist. 2.Check your folder's permissions making sure that your server can write to them.

Comment: I tried 
  
$url = 'G:/' ;   

   if (!is_writeable()) 
   {
      die("$url __________ is not writeable");
   }
everything I getting NOT writeable. Is there some installation to switch on ?

Comment: is my URL format correct ?    $url = 'G:/' ;

Comment: I don't know how you have your directory set up.  You can use something like $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get your root directory and then append a path to it like this:  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myFolder/myfile.pdf'; Please read on these functions: mkdir() and chmod().

Comment: Got some light here. Appatently, i was trying to write to folder which are not writable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845814/fopen-doesn%C2%B4t-work-with-something-different-than-r-php